# router.navigate occasionally not changing view

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm not sure why, but the navigation to the home page after login is working most times. Occasionally, however, the app will stay on the login page and not load the home page as it should.

I added .then and console.logs but even when it failed I get 'navigation successful' in the console. I'm not sure what else to look for. It works probably 75% of the time, but I get nothing in the console when it fails to explain why.

When it fails there is no message in the console, no error that I can see, the page view stays on the login form, the address bar of the browser doesn't change and to top it off I DO get the toast message right above it. I've also tried moving the toast to after the navigate call, and will still get the toast even when it doesn't navigate. So I don't think the toastService is affecting it in any way.

`public submitLogin(Login) {
    this.loginService.login(Login.value.email, Login.value.password)
        .subscribe(
            () => {
                this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Login', 'Successfully logged in');
                this.router.navigate(['./home']).then(
                    () => console.log('navigation successful'),
                    () => console.log('navigation failed')
                );
            },
            err => {
                this.error = ApiHelper.buildErrorStringFromResponse(this.Login.controls, err);
            }
        );
}`

Comment: please provide the url's you are refering to.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, login is at /login, and after successfully logging in, it should navigate to /home. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Yes. what happens when you give wrong credentials?

Comment: The this.error variable is set, and I get a message that was returned by the server about the problem.

Comment: I think I found something, not sure if its a solution, but if I do ```setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate(['./home']), 0)``` it seems to work every time (just got it 20 times in a row). I think there is some sort of race condition going on that I can't track down. I'm not sure if this counts as an answer...

Comment: try to add log on the home page constructor, maybe the home page loads and return back to login? can you provide the routes as well?

Comment: Can you post your route resolve? You probably have a race condition. The solution might be a timeout, but don't do that because it is hacky. use `.delay(1)` before your subscribe to let the observable do the timeout delay for you (not that it is much different than a timeout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution is because I wasn't using .share() and so the subscribes weren't always being executed in a fixed order. To the original http call I added .share() before adding the subscribes and now it always runs correct.